# Xcode static analyzer and copyWithZone

Tags: objective-c, ios, reference-counting, clang-static-analyzer

The Xcode 4 static analyzer flags this method as a having an over-released return value when that does not seem to be the case.

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithURL:self.url postString:self.postString];
}
```

There is an arrow pointing from the return keyword to the expression following it, and another from that expression to the analyzer warning.  Here is the static analysis:

1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count
2. Object sent -autorelease message
3. Object returned to caller as an owning reference (single retain count transferred to caller)
4. Object returned to caller with a +0 (non-owning) retain count
5. Object with +0 retain counts returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

Is the static analyzer incorrect or is there something wrong with this code?

---

By request, the `-initWithURL:postString:` method:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)u postString:(NSString *)p
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) ) 
    {
        self.url = u;
        self.postString = p;
    }
    return self;
}
```

---

I continue to get this warning even after cleaning and rebuilding the project.

**UPDATE:** The Xcode static analyzer no longer flags this as an issue after upgrading to Xcode 4.2.

Comment: Hmm... can you also post your initWithURL:postString: method?

Comment: @Jason: I've just created a new class using just the above, and I can't duplicate this with Xcode 4.0.2. When you click on the "2. Object sent autorelease" analysis, which arrow gets highlighted?

Comment: @spacehunt: Clicking the arrows doesn't do anything.  I created a new project and added the .h/.m file to it and nothing is flagged by the static analyzer.  As a result I assume this must be a bug in the static analyzer.

Comment: How about a screenshot of the arrows and warning. Part of this story has to be missing.

Comment: a standard mention for Xcode - have you quit and restarted it?

Comment: Also, what version (exactly) of XCode are you running (and do you have multiple versions installed)?

Comment: What does your url and postString properties look like?

Comment: Could it actually be talking about the next or previous method in the file and just gotten confused about the location?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback.  This is no longer flagged as an error in Xcode 4.2, so I assume this was a bug in the static analyzer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug in Xcode. The code is alright.

Comment: This seems to be the case, since Xcode 4.2 no longer flags this code as an issue.